# Pegando valor de um campo SQL depois do retorno da função

Tags: php

Como eu faço para pegar um determinado valor da tabela SQL após eu ter feito um select. Sempre irá retornar um único valor

```
$sql = "SELECT MAX(cod_periodo) from periodo_edital";
$query = $this->db->query($sql);
$result = $query->result();
```

Esse é meu código preciso acessar o campo cod_periodo. 
Existe algum comando especifico para executar?

Comment: Experimenta dar um var_dump na variável `$result`, talvez já fique mais fácil de resolver

Comment: Ele retorna correto, porém na hora de eu usar o $cod_periodo na minha query ele insere como () e da erro no banco

Comment: Parece que não esta vindo o campo que você quer, coloca a query na pergunta, talvez o problema esteja lá.

Comment: Alterei, mas surgiu outro problema. Ele retorna um array como faço para pegar o valor string que ele retornou e mudar para inteiro

Comment: Você usa PDO ou mysqli?

Comment: To utilizando PDO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode criar um nome (alias) para o MAX da consulta, facilita na hora do uso.

```
$sql = "SELECT MAX(cod_periodo) AS max_cod_pedido from periodo_edital";
```

e para recuperar o valor que vai retornar como um array você pode fazer assim:

```
echo $result[0]->max_cod_pedido;
```

dentro do `$result[0]` provavelmente vai existir um objeto

e que você acesso a atributo com `->max_cod_pedido`

se for um array

```
echo $result[0][max_cod_pedido];
```

Como você comentou que o retorno é de linha unica, não a necessidade de iterar.

Porém talvez seja legal validar o existe o resultado esperado, afim de não gerar erros.

Algo assim, por exemplo:

```
if (isset($result[0])) {
```

Comment: Deu certo, muito Obrigado!